# Disciplined badge is not showing in my inbox as a notification

Tags: bug, badges

I looked up for something similar, but this one was the closes I could get to this bug: ["Not a Robot" badge is not showing in their profile badge count](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336524/not-a-robot-badge-is-not-showing-in-their-profile-badge-count)

Today I received 2 badges, the [`Census`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6644/census?userid=2180785) silver badge and a couple of hours later I got the [`Disciplined`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined?userid=2180785) bronze badge for deleting my own [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48069190/entry-point-for-reading-a-properties-file-located-in-file-system-with-struts-2)

However I only got a notification in my "inbox" for the `Census` badge, as you can see in the following screenshot with the obligatory hand-made red circle:

[image]

Ordered by recently awarded badges:
[image]

Even on StackExchange app I get this:

[image]